# share backbone code on client and server side with mongodb storage

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js

I'm looking for a solution to code only once the models for a backbone, mongodb, nodejs based app.

The storage can be only server side, but I still need proper model definitions both on the server and the client. On the server side I've decided to go with mongodb.

After all the only thing I've found is https://github.com/donedotcom/backbone-mongodb.

I think I've understood backbone quite well, but have never use mongodb before, and I can't figure out how to really use backbone-mongodb. Could someone tell me how it complements backbone, what Document and EmbeddedDocument are meant for and how they related to Backbone.Model? Does this have anything to do with code sharing b/w client and server?

Of course, my idea would be to share the model definitions and validation (done mostly with backbone-validation) b/w the server and the client.

thanks, Viktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just finished rewriting [backbone-mongodb](https://github.com/ToolPartTeam/backbone-mongodb)

there is [an example todo application](https://github.com/nagyv/backbone-mongodb-todo) (stay with commit eb935ae7480c18c9d6fcf2f5a2187cdff3d17a13) available as well

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

- `Document` <-> `Backbone.Model`
- Read and write data on Node.js by overriding `Backbone.sync`.
- `EmbeddedDocument` no exact match: probably possible to implement via [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational), some assembly required.

**Long read**

Since MongoDB is a document-centric database `Backbone.Model`'s will fit Mongo's Document's quite nicely. You can think about MongoDB's Documents as if you could store searchable JSON blobs (..oversimplification for the sake of getting started, but still). They will more will more or less be an exact match to Backbones Models. EmbeddedDocument's corresponds somewhat (..oversimplification again, same reason) to related tables in traditional relational systems. They don't have an exact match in the Backbone world, but you could possible use [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) to handle them in your Node application. I haven't tried it but I'm making a qualified guess that it will need certain amount of hand-holding.

On the Node side, you'll want to override `Backbone.sync`, probably globally to read and write `Model`objects to MongoDB Documents.

Also, embedded documents are just that - they are the actual data stored *inside* another object, not a link to that data stored independently ([docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking)). It's also possible to do links, which are more like traditional relations (see same link).

To be able to correctly program something with this combination, I think you should read at least a bit more on MongoDB, here's some pointers:

- [Getting started with MongoDB and Python](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-python.html), Python-centric but still a very good introduction to MongoDB.
- Have you checked out [this MongoDB port of the typical Backbone Todo](http://code.emilientaque.fr/toying-with-backbonejs-nodejs-mongodb.html)?
- [Here](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)'s another example of someone describing a webapp using Node & MongoDB. It's not Backbone-driven but it'll still show you a lot about how to work with MongoDB from Node.js.

Comment: thanks, I know the links except for the first one

the other two are not related to my question as they don't use backbone at all on the server side